# PHP, is it acceptable to include a php file not at top of the file to get around the limitations of the header() function?

Tags: php, html, header, include

I apologise for the trivial question, but I have been having problems using the header() php function to redirect to pages. More specifically I am struggling to redirect a user when he/she tries to view a non existent profile page. My problem is that I am always including a header file which contains session start and some html to display a basic header. Does this mean I cannot use the header() function to redirect to pages in my scripts that include this header file? 
I thought one way to get around the problem might be to split the html part of the header into a separate file, and include the header scripts first, then write my profile scripts, and finally include the html part of the header. Is that bad practice? the profile.php script follows:

```
<?php include("inc/incfiles/header.inc.php"); ?>
<?php

if(isset($_GET['u'])) {

    //check user exists

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);

    if (ctype_alnum($username)) {

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($check)===1) {

            $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check); //execute query and store in array

            $username = $get['username'];

            $email = $get['email'];

        }

        else {
            header("Location: index.php");

            die();

        }

    }

    else {

        echo "username has to be alphanumeric";

    }

}

else {

    echo "error";

}

?>


<h2> Profile page of <?php echo "$username";?>


<h3> Email: <?php echo "$email";?>
```

header.inc.php file:

```
<?php

include ("inc/scripts/mysql_connect.inc.php");

//start the session


session_start();

//Checks whether the user is logged in

$user = $_SESSION["user_login"];

if (!isset($SESSION["user_login"])) {

//header("Location: index.php");

//exit();


}

else

{

    header("location: home.php");

}


?>

<?php


//Login Scripts has to be at the top to make sure header() redirecting works


if (isset($_POST["user_login"]) && isset($_POST["password_login"])) {

$user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','', $_POST["user_login"]); //filter user login text

$password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','', $_POST["password_login"]); //filter user password text

$md5password_login = md5($password_login);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$user_login' AND 
password='$md5password_login' LIMIT 1"); //query the user


//Check for user's existence

$userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); //count number of rows

if ($userCount == 1) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

        $id = $row["id"];

    }


    $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;

    $_SESSION["password_login"] = $md5password_login;



header("Location: home.php");


    exit();


}

else {

    echo "That information is incorrect, try again";

}

}



?>



<html>

<head>

    <link href = "css/main.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css">

    <title> title </title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class = "wrapper">

        <div id = "header">

            <div class = "logo">

                <img src = "img/Logo.png">

        </div>

            <div id = "login-header">


                    <form action = "index.php" method ="post" name = "form1" id = "form1">

                            <div class = "input-wrapper"><input type = "text" size = "25" name = "user_login" id = "user_login" placeholder = ">Username" ></div>

                            <div class = "input-wrapper"><input type = "password" size = "25" name = "password_login" id = "password_login" placeholder = "Password" ></div>

                            <div class = "input-wrapper"><input type = "submit" name = "login" value = "Sign in"></div>

                    </form>


            </div>


        <div id = "menu">

            <a href = "#"></a>

            <a href = "#"></a>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you can do that but you can not call header() function after code/file that has <head></head> section in. In that case you would get headers already sent error. Are you getting one of those ?

Comment: Also, what does your header.inc.php file look like and where are you calling the header() function in your code ? Is there any specific error message that you are getting ?

Comment: I have added the header file, the problem I am having when including it is that it does not redirect to index.php succesfully, it will redirect to index.php but only load the header. Thanks

Comment: and sorry I had deleted the header() call and forgot to add it again. I have added that as well now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include files wherever you want. The problem is **OUTPUT**. If you're going to be doing `header()` calls, you cannot have performed **ANY** output prior to the call. If your includes are simply spitting out output, and are not just defining functions/vars for later use, then you'll have to have to modify the includes to NOT do that output, or at least buffer/defer the output until later. e.g.

```
<?php

include('some_file_that_causes_output_when_loaded.php');
header('This header will not work');
```

will fail no matter what, because your include did output, and kills the header call. But if you mod the include, so you have something more like:

```
<?php

include('file_that_just_defines_functions.php');
header('This header will work');
function_from_include_that_causes_output();
```

will work just fine. If you can't mod the code, then

```
<?php

ob_start();
include('some_file_that_causes_output_when_loaded.php');
header('This header will still work, because we're buffering output');
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: I have just tried adding ob_start() before including the header.inc.php file and I have added ob_end_clean at the end of the profile php script and that does not display the header markup when I actually want it to (when the profile exists). When the profile does not exist the redirect still has the problem of not showing anything but the header (missing the rest of the index.php output) I'll try putting all the output of the header in a function and calling it and see if that works! in the mean time thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: does ob_start() hold only echo""; outputs or also the plain html ones?

Comment: it holds ANY output. if it's something that'd go out over the wire to the client browser, the OB system will buffer it.